# how to get a $parameter from a form submit at form action=""

Tags: php, forms, parameters

i am working on a search module. I want to set the parameter that the user adds in the input filed at the url like www.demo.com/index.php?keyword=wordtobesearched

the following code works with a delay.. meaning at the first search i get nothing in the url  ?keyword= 
at the second search i get the word i used in the first search

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $sess->purl( $mm_action_url."index.php" )?>?keyword=<?php echo $_POST$keyword; ?>"  >
        <input type="text" name="keyword" />    
 </form >
```

Any idea how to get the keyword the user search at first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your method to get then it appends the keyword to the url for you.

```
  <form method = "GET" ....
```

Comment: with GET i receive the variable on the url as i want but the results page doesnt prompt :/  the action of the form is : action="<?php $sess->purl( $mm_action_url."index.php?page=shop.browse" ) ?>. adding ?keyword=<?php echo $_POST["keyword"]; gives me on the url the wordsearch of the previous search